# Adding formatting tags to textbox value

Tags: jquery

In my form I want to allow the user to format text and add lists and such (basic html functionality, without having to know html).

Using the Bold button as an example:

```
<div class="goBold button">B</div>
<input type="text" name="txtMessage" />
<script>
$(".goBold").click(function() {
    formatText("bold");
});

function formatText(formatType)
{
    var input = $("#txtMessage");
    var text = input.val();
    var ss = input[0].selectionStart;
    var se = input[0].selectionEnd;

    if (formatType == "bold")
    {
        if (ss == se)
        {
            // there's no text in the textbox, so just write in the tags
            input.val(text + "[b][/b]");
        }
        else
        {
            // surround the highlighted text with the tags
            input.val(text.substr(0, ss) + "[b]" + text.substr(ss, se) + "[/b]" + text.substring(se, text.length));
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

While all this works, there is a slight problem:

Lets assume my text value for this textbox is

> The quick red fox jumps over the lazy brown dog. This is the only sentence in the English language that uses all 26 letters of the alphabet

With the words `all 26 letters` highlighted, clicking the bold button will wrap the text in the tags, but it will also add a second copy of the text that exists after the selection.

I'm not sure why this is, can anyone provide any insight here?

TIA :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `substring` everywhere :

```
input.val(text.substring(0, ss) + 
          "[b]" + text.substring(ss, se) + "[/b]" + 
          text.substring(se, text.length));
```

(BTW, your selector should be `$("input[name=txtMessage]")` - it has no id).

Comment: good note on the selector there, but that was just a typo when I wrote in the code haha I'll fix

Comment: Well that works, thanks :) Only, I think I need to change the default (no selection) so that it inserts the tags wherever the user's current position in the textbox is (the flashing pipe thing lol dunno what it's called) though I'm not sure how to do that either

Comment: HAH turns out it was easier than expected :) yay

Answer (score 1):

substr takes two paramaters - start and **length**. You're using the second parameter as the end position instead of length.

```
text.substr(0, ss) + "[b]" + text.substr(ss, se-ss) + "[/b]" + text.substring(se)
```

The above code will correctly position the [b] tags.

Alternatively, substring (instead of substr) takes start and end parameters instead of start and length